# How to approach doing a full time load for my data in Oracle to MariaDB?

Tags: python, oracle, mariadb, cdata

I'm not sure how to go about doing a one time load of the existing data I have in Oracle to MariaDB. I have DBeaver which I am using to access the databases. I saw an option in DBeaver to migrate the data from Source (Oracle) to Target (MariaDB) with a few clicks, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

Is writing a python script a better way of doing it? Should I download another tool to do a one time load? We are using CData Sync to do the incremental loads. Basically, it copies data from one database to another (Oracle to SQL Server for example) and it does incremental loads. I'm not sure if I can use it to do a full time/one time load of all the data I have in my Oracle database to MariaDB. I'm new to this, I've never loaded data before. The thing is, I have over 1100 tables so I can't manually write the schema for each table and do a "CREATE TABLE" statement for all 1100 tables...

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** DBeaver

If DBeaver is willing to try it in a few clicks I'd try and see what it gives for some small tables.

**Option 2** MariaDB connect

Alternately there [MariaDB connect engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/oracle-xe-112-and-mariadb-101-integration-on-ubuntu-1404-and-debian-systems/#mariadb) using ODBC or JDBC.

Note you don't need to create table structure for all, but do need the list of table and generate `CREATE TABLE t1 ENGINE=CONNECT TABLE_TYPE=ODBC tabname='T1' CONNECTION='DSN=XE;..` for each table.

Then it would be:

```
create database mariadb_migration;
create table mariadb_migration.t1 like t1;
insert into mariadb_migration.t1 select * from t1;
```

**Option 3** MariaDB Oracle Mode

This uses the [Oracle compatibility mode of MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modeoracle/).

1. Take a SQL dump from Oracle.
2. Prepend `SET SQL_MODE='ORACLE';` to start of the dump.
3. Import this to MariaDB.

**Option 4** SQLines

SQLines offer a [Oracle to MariaDB](https://sqlines.com/oracle-to-mariadb)

Small disclaimer, I've not done any of these personally, I just know these options exist.